# Haskell deriving additional instances for imported datatypes

Tags: haskell, import, types, typeclass

I'm relatively new to Haskell. I write a clone of the card game uno and i want pretty coloured output of a card. I do

```
import System.Console.ANSI
```

which provides

```
data Color = Black
           | Red
           | Green
           | Yellow
           | Blue
           | Magenta
           | Cyan
           | White
           deriving (Bounded, Enum, Show)
```

now i want to add deriving (Ord, Eq) as well, i could write this in the source file of the imported package, but there should be an easier way to do this.
i don't have a clue what keywords to google for or look for in a book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to edit the library. In your source file, state:

```
instance Eq Color where
  x == y  =  fromEnum x == fromEnum y

instance Ord Color where
  compare x y  =  compare (fromEnum x) (fromEnum y)
```

Explanation: `fromEnum` is a function on `Enum` that returns an `int` (`Black -> 0`, `Red -> 1`, etc.). Integers are obviously equality-comparable and ordered.

**Edit**: @rampion's version, in the comments, is obviously prettier:

```
instance Eq Color where
  (==)  =  (==) `on` fromEnum

instance Ord Color where
  compare  =  compare `on` fromEnum
```

Comment: For the read-typeclass I added the following lines

    `instance Read Color where¬
       readsPrec _ str   = [(color (c), t) |¬
                                   (c, t) ← reads str]¬
                         where color x = case x of "Black" → Black¬
                                                   "Red" → Red¬
                                                   "Green" → Green¬
                                                   "Yellow" → Yellow¬
                                                   "Blue" → Blue¬
                                                   ...`

Comment: Using `import Data.Function (on)`: `instance Eq Color where (==) = (==) \`on\` fromEnum`, `instance Ord Color where compare = compare \`on\` fromEnum`.

Comment: Can't he use standalone deriving do derive Ord and Eq automagically? http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Stand-alone_deriving_declarations

Comment: With a GHC extension, I don't remember which, you can say `deriving instance Eq Color` and get the `deriving(..)` behavior

Comment: @Rafael: I tend not to use GHC extensions needlessly, and certainly not teach them to novice users.